# Module not found: Can't resolve 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css' in 'C:\Users\test\counter-app\src'

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-component

I'm new to react js. I'm trying to create a component. For that I've installed bootstrap (version 4.1.1) which is successfully installed.

Then I imported the same in index.js and while reloading the page (localhost:3000) I got the error msg:

> ```
> Module not found: 
> Can't resolve 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css' in 'C:\Users\test\counter-app\src'
> ```

My `index.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

My `package.json` :

```
{
  "name": "counter-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.4",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: You `package.json` is missing `bootstrap`. Run `npm install bootstrap`

Comment: Hi @lupa, this isn’t necessarily the case in general, as the module could be installed within the node_modules directory and could be used within the app to test if this is a module worth keeping. You only add dependencies to the package.json once you’re sure you’re using this module and want it to be listed as a build dependency moving forward. But in this case I think the issue is, as you pointed out as well, the module wasn’t installed correctly. Hopefully that makes sense :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change import path to bootstrap.min.css like this:

> import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

Comment: Problem is cus you don't have installed bootstrap. You can check that in "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.4",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8"
  },

when you install bootstrap or some another library in your react project you should see that in package.json / dependencies part.

Comment: execute this command "npm install bootstrap". After that check package.json does you have boottrap defined there.
Let me know if works.

Comment: Great..! now it works. But I've already installed that by using the command : npm i bootstrapp@4.1.1. So why it doesn't work..?

Comment: Cus command which you execute is not correct: "npm i bootstrapp@4.1.1." you just need to execute "npm install bootstrap"

Answer (score 3):

This occurs either because the *installation of a library wasn't successful*, i.e. bootstrap had an issue installing within your `node_modules` directory, or your *reference to the library within your code is incorrect*. Can you verify that your `bootstrap` installation was correct by looking within your `node_modules` for a bootstrap folder?

This would be at `<base_path>/node_modules/bootstrap` where `<base_path>` is your project's root directory location. For you I believe the absolute path is the following:

```
C:\Users\test\counter-app\src\node_modules\bootstrap
```

If you don't see the `bootstrap` directory please do the following:

```
npm i -S bootstrap
```

as this will save bootstrap as dependency for your project. Your reference to `bootstrap` within `index.js` looks fine: `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/boostrap.css';` With that being said, a lot of bootstrap's features depend on the following libraries: `popper.js`, and `jquery`. So once you get your installation issue resolved you  have to install these modules as well and reference them appropriately within your `index.js`. Something along the lines of:

**Install modules:**

```
npm i -S popper.js
npm i -S jquery
```

**index.js**

```
import 'jquery/dist/jquery.js';
import 'popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js';
import 'boostrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js';
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thx this was really helpful, I was searching for this for a long time. One more suggestions, we can import `min` versions rather than regular versions.

Comment: @SaahithyanVigneswaran I'm glad to hear you found this answer useful. Yes you should use minified versions, for every library your application is dependent upon,  when deploying your code to a production level environment. However, for development it may be useful to use non-minified versions of dependency libraries in case you need to trace a stack trace to determine the root cause of a bug. I guess it is a matter of personal preference though.

Answer (score 0):

Using bootstrap like that is not really recommended. You should look into [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/). You would need to run:

```
npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap
```

and then:

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

// or less ideally
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

Check out their [documentation](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/getting-started/introduction) for more.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but managed to solve it using these steps:

1. Remove the `node_modules` folder
2. Install bootstrap by running `npm install bootstrap`
3. Install other packages by running `npm install`.

Answer (score 0):

Beware of confusing '`boostrap`' with '`bootsrap`'

Theese, install different packages:

```
$ npm install boostrap

$ npm install bootstrap
```

I was requiring the second. Because of that, I've got question's error.